# Why is [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden] added by default in custom WinRT C++/CX controls?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, visual-studio-2012, c++-cx

When I create a new control in a WinRT C++/CX project, the class attribute `[Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]` is added by default by Visual Studio 2012.

Example:

```
namespace WindowsRuntimeComponent1
{
    [Windows::Foundation::Metadata::WebHostHidden]
    public ref class MyUserControl sealed
    {
    public:
        MyUserControl();
    };
}
```

- Is there any documented reason for this?  (I did my homework but I
  failed to find this piece of information)
- As far as I know, using the attribute `[WebHostHidden]` makes the class
  invisible for WinRT HTML/Javascript projects. Does this mean that I
  cannot create a control in C++/CX that can be used in Javascript?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> As far as I know, using the attribute `[WebHostHidden]` makes the class invisible for WinRT HTML/JavaScript projects.

This is correct:  this attribute hides the type in the JavaScript projection, so from JavaScript it is as if the type does not exist.

> Does this mean that I cannot create a control in C++/CX that can be used in JavaScript?

You cannot use XAML controls from JavaScript, period.  When using JavaScript, UI is authored using HTML, not XAML.

Comment: Are there _other_ use cases, except from user authored control, which require this attribute ? for example, suppose I've C++/Cx component __not__ dealing w/ UI at all, under which circumstances one should annotate this component w/ WebHostHidden ?