# C# WinRT component fails in UserControl constructor calling from WinJS

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, winjs

We are building a WinRT application with JavaScript (WinJS) that accesses REST/JSON web services via C# WinRT Component library. In the component library we have a Logon control (much like WebAuthenticationBroker) that allowes us to use ACS logon with our REST services.

Application Layers:

- Client (JS)
- WinRT component dll (C#)
- C# ClassLibrary dll (C#)
- UserControl (Xaml/C#, contains WebView)

The problem: When trying to create the logon control, the WinRT throws "HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD)" exception (when entering the UserControl's constructor) ***even if I call it via Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher*** (recommended in MSDN [article I found about WinJS/C++ component](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh755833%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

If I call it from a Xaml/C# client, the code works with or without the Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow.GetForCurrentThread().Dispatcher.RunAsync().

I've tried to google this and also read all the UserControl, Dispatcher and WinJS documentation but I have not found anything relevant. Is this a known problem and could someone suggest a workaround?

Since I'm a first time poster, please be gentle :-) Any help is extremely welcome!

Comment: Could you post a short sample code that shows the problem? (Both the C# and the JS side.)

Comment: I'll try to whip up something tomorrow. The current code is not easy to demonstrate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Xaml-based WinRT controls cannot be used in Javascript-based WinRT projects.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12713334/501196) You can use any WinRT class library, but not Xaml controls inside them.

If you still want to combine HTML-Javascript with Xaml, I would recommend creating a Xaml-based project, and wrapping  your HTML UI in a [WebView control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx).

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately this confirms my fears. How is it that one cannot make UI's in winrt components?!? Somehow I would have thought that would be one of the main reasons for making them... Well, one more "microsoftism" to remember.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect it to be possible to use WinRT/XAML UI in an HTML/WinJS app. You would probably need to use some callbacks to request the UI to be created in a WinJS app/component library instead of the XAML one.

Comment: Thanks for the idea of callback.